# Present value of annuity

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The problem is :

Given a discount rate of $5\%$ compounded quarterly, what’s the PV of an annuity-due with annual payment $1,300$ for $5$ years?

It's annuity due so $a\ double\ dot\ n$. $1300 \ a \ double \ dot \ 5$

Following the formula, I would do $\frac{1-(\frac{.05}{4})^{20}}{\frac{\frac{.05}{4}}{1+\frac{.05}{4}}}$ since the denominator is $d=\frac{i}{i+1}$

This is nowhere near the answer provided. Intuition and correct set up is appreciated

Comment: Isn't the formula for the present value of a uniform annuity $\frac{(1+i)^N-1}{i(1+i)^N}$? Does that give the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $p=1300$ the annual payment for $n=5$ years and $d^{(4)}=5\%$ discount rate compounded quarterly. So  $1-d=\left(1-\frac{d^{(4)}}{4}\right)^4=\frac1{1+i}$ and the annual effective discount rate is $d=4.91\%$ and the annual effective interest rate is $i=5.16\%$. The present value of the annuity due is
$$
PV=p\times \ddot a_{\overline{n}|i}=p\times (1+i)a_{\overline{n}|i}=p\times (1+i)\frac{1-(1+i)^{-5}}{i}
$$
Observing that $\frac{1+i}{i}=\frac{1}{d}$ 
$$
PV=p\times \frac{1-(1-d)^{5}}{d}=p\times 4\,\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{d^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{20}}{d^{(4)}}=5,892.28
$$

You can also evaluate directly from
$$
\begin{align}
PV&=p+p (1-d)+p(1-d)^2+p (1-d)^3+p(1-d)^4\\
&=p+p \left(1-\frac{d^{(4)}}{4}\right)^4+p\left(1-\frac{d^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{8}+p \left(1-\frac{d^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{12}+p\left(1-\frac{d^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{16}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. I have one additional question, what would the formula be if we wanted to evaluate directly for $FV$?

Comment: $$
FV=p\times \ddot s_{\overline{n}|i}=p\times \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{d}=p\times \frac{(1-d)^{-n}-1}{d}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Quarterly Rate = $ 0.0125$

PV of Annuity Due $= 1300+ \dfrac{1300}{(1+0.0125)^4} + \dfrac{1300}{(1+0.0125)^8}+\dfrac{1300}{(1+0.0125)^{12}}+\dfrac{1300}{(1+0.0125)^{16}}$
=$5899.63$